# Will changing the date or time on windows server 2008 break any websites or anything else?

Tags: windows-server-2008, time, date

Sorry if this is a newb question, but I was told by someone about a month ago that if I change the date and/or time on one of our servers it could break our websites or something. I can't fully remember who told me or what they actually said... but we have a Windows Server 2008 that is 1 hour 12 minutes slow and it is messing with one of my websites event logs (which we need to be as accurate as possible) So my question is:

If I change the time (Control Panel>Date and Time>Change Date and Time>update time) will I screw ANYTHING up? I am truly hoping the fix will be this simple but knowing my luck it's going to be a 10 hour process to update

Thank you!

Comment: Basically, what DanBig said, but I just wanted to say that I suspect that the person who told you that was thinking of Active Directory and setting the time to be incorrect.  An oldie but goodie:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742516.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is an IIS server, you will have incorrectly dated (time) log files (existing files will now be that 1h12m behind), but that's about it.